# Concatanate RTF files with PHP withouth header

Tags: php, ms-word, rtf

I have some RTF files generated by users with Microsoft Word. I need to be able to concatenate these files, and the result file should still be readable by libreoffice. I'm using libreoffice in order to convert the result file into a PDF file.

In order to concatenate two files, my application remove the last character of the first file and the first one of my other file. The files headers are not removed (I'm not speaking about page header).

For some reason, libreoffice do not like the headers inserted by Microsoft Word. But it works fine if I open these files with Wordpad and save them.

Another way to remove these headers is to convert these files into RTF before I concatenate them. This way i can convert into PDF, but libreoffice make a serious mess with my tabs when i convert my files to RTF.

So how can I remove the headers through PHP withouth messing with tabs ? Or do you have another way to get to the same result ?

Edit :

In a nutshell, I must be able to concanate these files and that libreoffice could open it. And my tabs must still display nicely in Microsoft Word.

As you can guess, users don't want to use Wordpad. And my customer's IT department has to comply to that wish ( office politics).

UPDATE :

I have to do the merging first, because of business rules. The files are merged, then my users can modify it using Word (no problems here). Then they ask their boss to validate it. If the boss agree to validate, the RTF file become a PDF file.

**UPDATE 2 :**

I have a begenning of a solution. If the RTF file start by plain text or a picture, you have to remove everything until you get \pard. But this does not work if you file start by a tab.

**UPDATE 3 :**

If you want to support tab too, you have to remove evrything until you get \pard or \trowd. I'm going to post the total solution once i get a working code. This will works fine as long you don't need colours and that all yours files use the same font (because we don't remove the RTF headers of the first file).

Comment: Do you have to do the merging first and the conversion to PDF afterwards? If it's just concatenating pages, and converting a single RTF to PDF works fine and doesn't cause problems with LibreOffice, you can do that first and then use a tool like [`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/) to merge the single PDF documents.

Comment: I have updated my post. I have to do the merging first, because business rules allow the user to modify the file after the concatenation. It became PDF once it has been validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed to build a reliable code, which make possible to manipulate the RTF files created with Microsoft Word. It works as long as you only need text, pictures and tabs, and don't need fancy things as color. Color works for text, but beside that ...

```
        $content = "";

        //stristr Returns all of haystack starting from and including the first occurrence of needle to the end. 
        $tmp_pard = stristr($RTFstring, "\pard");
        //stristr fail to detect \trowd
        $tmp_tab = stristr($RTFstring, "trowd");

        if($tmp_pard != "" || $tmp_tab != "") {

            //We pick the longer string. Because we want the first occurence of \pard or \trowd
            if(strlen($tmp_pard) > strlen($tmp_tab))
                // { is added so concatenation code still works. We just remove headers.
                $content =  "{" . substr($RTFstring,-strlen($tmp_pard)) ;
            else
                $content =  "{" . "\\". substr($RTFstring,-strlen($tmp_tab))  ;
        } else {
            $content = $RTFstring;
        }

        return $content;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the limitations with the 'pure RTF' approach come back to bite you, you could use LibreOffice to convert your RTF files to docx, then use a tool to merge the docx files.

There are such tools for .NET and Java (such as our MergeDocx product); I'm not sure what you'll find for PHP.

Comment: Does the RTF to docx convertion works nice on libreoffice ? I tryied RTF to RTF and RTF to DOCX then DOCX to RTF. In these both ways libreoffice did a mess with tabs.                                                               Anyway I can't got this way. We are using RTF because it is plain text, so we can easily do some search and replace in php. And right before the file(already merged) become PDF, I have to sign it. So it must be RTF, and libreoffice don't do a good job at converting something to RTF.

Comment: The limitations of the 'pure RTF' approach won't come back to bite me. At least, my customer won't ask for colours in tabs or such fancy things. This is an Administration so they are happy with text, tabs and pictures. They won't even use another color than black for text.